# SQL query where i aggregate count based its status

Tags: sql, postgresql

| user | enabled_app | app_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| h@gmail.com | active | 2553 |
| h@gmail.com | inactive | 2553 |
| h@gmail.com | waiting | 2553 |
| h@gmail.com | active | 2554 |
| b@gmail.com | active | 2555 |
| b@gmail.com | waiting | 2555 |
| b@gmail.com | active | 2556 |

I have a above table, and expected output would be

| email | count |
| --- | --- |
| h@gmail.com | 1 |
| b@gmail.com | 2 |

Let me explain we are displaying each user has how many enabled app which are active state.

So lets take the first email id **h@gmail.com** which returns 1 because this user has 2 app_id associated with it. 2553 and 2554. now in 2553 we wont consider because although it has active it also has an inactive value in it. But for app_id 2554 we have an active enabled_app but there is no inactive value for it. Hence **h@gmail.com**  has count as 1

similarly b@gmail.com    has 2 active apps of different app_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    [user], COUNT([app_id])
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    enabled_app = 'active'
    AND [app_id] NOT IN (SELECT [app_id] FROM YourTable WHERE enabled_app = 'inactive')
GROUP BY
    [user]
```

Comment: Thanks for that reinforcement, Simon. I was wondering what was wrong with it myself. :-)

Comment: Maybe because it's invalid standard SQL and won't work with Postgres because of those square brackets?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
select t1."user", 
       count(*)
from the_table t1
where enabled_app = 'active'
  and not exists (select * 
                  from the_table t2
                  where t2."user" = t1."user"
                    and t2.app_id = t1.app_id
                    and t2.enabled_app = 'inactive')
group by t1."user"
order by t1."user"
```

Comment: I would change the * for 1 instead at the inner query. It would work the same way but faster.

Comment: @HugoVares: no that's a myth that has never been true. The expression inside an EXIST or NOT EXISTS subquery is never evaluated. The database doesn't even look at it. I could even write `select 1/0` without it throwing an error. In fact in Postgres I can even leave it out completely because SELECT without a column list is also allowed.

Comment: The real *performance experts* use `select NULL` as it is not only "faster", but also *confusing* @HugoVares

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: I think `select false` might be even more confusing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `EXCEPT`  (aka *minus*) you get a raw data of the active applications that are not in *inactive* state

```
select "user", app_id from tab where enabled_app = 'active'
except 
select "user", app_id from tab where enabled_app = 'inactive'
```

As a positive effect the *set operation* removes *duplicates*, so you need not to thing about if `count (distinct ...` should be used.

The next step is a simple aggregation

```
with tab2 as (
select "user", app_id from tab where enabled_app = 'active'
except 
select "user", app_id from tab where enabled_app = 'inactive'
)
select "user", count(*)
from tab2
group by 1
```